# JobTracker failing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I start up Hadoop, everything other than the JobTracker starts up (tasktracker, namenode, datanode, secondarynamenode).

In the JobTracker log, it tells me that it has problems connecting to port 50030 of the host, even though I definied mapred.job.tracker at port 54311 in the mapred-site.xml. Am I misunderstanding something here? Why is it trying to connect to port 50030 to begin with?

Also, for some reason it's trying to bind to an address that's a concatentation of the host name and the host ip, followed by the port number 50030. Is that normal?

... to be honest I'm not 100% sure I'm actually understanding the error message in the log, so I'll just post it..

```
2012-06-15 11:50:51,538 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Scheduler configured with (memSizeForMapSlotOnJT, memSizeForReduceSlotOnJT, limitMaxMemForMapTasks, limitMaxMemForReduceTasks) (-1, -1, -1, -1)
2012-06-15 11:50:51,579 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcMetrics: Initializing RPC Metrics with hostName=JobTracker, port=54311
2012-06-15 11:50:51,644 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2012-06-15 11:50:51,753 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50030
2012-06-15 11:50:51,755 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:425)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:3702)
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: After the discussion with Chris, I'm going to take an educated guess that a coworker of mine may have been using that port. I don't know, I'll see on Monday if things get better.

Comment: use `ps axww | grep JobTracker` to assert that you haven't got another job tracker already running

Comment: I don't think there is one. The command you wrote just gives me
 1755 pts/16   S+     0:00 grep JobTracker
, and it seems to me that that's just the grep process.

Comment: Ok, does `netstat -atn | grep 50030` show anything?

Comment: Yes, there are two lines, one for port 50030 and one for port 17788 for whatever reason. It says that both are "Established". I think they're listening to each other.

Comment: if you have root privs, run `netstat -atnp | grep 50030` and examine the pid column (the last column), then run another `ps ww -p ${pid}` to find the process that's using port 50030

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the root, so I couldn't access the pid column.

Comment: Ok, so stop everything hadoop related and run `ps axww | grep java | grep hadoop` - what java processes are still running that reference hadoop in some way?

Comment: After stopping hadoop and running that series of commands, I get nothing. This is really confounding me. I'm pretty sure I had JobTracker working before I started using Hive. I'm going to go over what I did to install Hive and see if anything I did over there may have affected it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing `mapred.job.tracker` with `mapred.job.tracker.http.address`.

Try this experiment in `mapred-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:50031</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:50032</value>
</property>
```

Then do your `start-mapred.sh` and go to `http://X.X.X.X:50032/jobtracker.jsp`

This should rule out the specific port that was under suspicion as well as illustrate that there are two different ports that matter.

More than likely you were trying to re-use the same port on the same machine for a different purpose.

Comment: Typically the first value (where I have 50031) is 8021, one after the name node's port.  The second value (where I have 50032) is usually 50030.

Answer (score 0):

For me rebooting the slave server helped. Please ensure that the network interface is up after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

this works like a charm

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:50031</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:50032</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the JobTracker service it's not starting, you need to execute this:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

If you didn't do it yet.

(In my case, `$HADOOP_HOME` is in `/usr/local/hadoop`)